# Scoped javascript callback in scala lift

Tags: ajax, scala, callback, closures, lift

So I've been playing around with Lift in Scala, and I've been enjoying it a lot.  I might just be missing something that exists in the lift javascript library, but I haven't been able to find any way of using a scoped javascript callback.  It seems that the lift way of handling callbacks is to pass the callback as function name and have lift return a JsCmd that Call()s the function.

My lift code is heavily based on this example http://demo.liftweb.net/json_more
And my javascript looks kinda like

```
function operation(config) {
    var actions = config.actions,
        action = actions.shift(),
        name = config.name;

    function chainAction(response) {
        if (actions.length > 0) {
            action = actions.shift();
            action.action(name, chainAction);
        }
    }

    action.action(name, chainAction);
}

operation({
    name: "ajax",
    actions: [
        { action: ajaxCall1 },
        { action: ajaxCall2 }
    ]
});
```

Where I'd want ajaxCall1 and ajaxCall2, to be AJAX calls to lift.  i.e. callNoParam() in the lift example, and chainAction to be the scoped callback.  Is there a way to do this in lift that I'm missing?  For clarity, I have been able to get this code to call the lift function, but not to handle the callback correctly.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Upon reading through the lift-generated javascript code, it looks like there are indeed placeholders for success/failure callbacks.  In particular, it looks like this line of lift

```
AllJsonHandler.is.jsCmd
```

is generating this line of javascript

```
function F86737576748N5SY25(obj) {liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F86737576748N5SY25='+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)), null,null);}
```

which references this method

```
lift_ajaxHandler: function(theData, theSuccess, theFailure, responseType)
```

But not allowing me to pass theSuccess or theFailure which look like they are being passed along into jQuery.ajax() calls.  My investigation continues.  If anyone has any good resources on is.jsCmd it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the `SHtml.ajaxCall` function? I don't know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Part of the reason why you haven't gotten an answer is that the question is really confusing. I think I can answer it though, if I can be sure what you want. It appears that you want a Javascript function to use AJAX to call something on the server side and the server side part will then call `chainAction(response)` with the response when it is complete. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a piece of code that adds a Javascript function `doCallback` to the page (in `#placeholder`). This function will print a line to the console and then do an ajaxCall back to the server to the function `commandCallback`.

```
def addExecuteCallback(ns: NodeSeq):NodeSeq = {
  val log = JsRaw("console.log('[doCallback] Generated from Lift.');").cmd &
            SHtml.ajaxCall(JsRaw("commandString"), commandCallback _)._2.cmd
  val f = JsCmds.Function("doCallback", List[String](), log)
  ("#placeholder" #> JsCmds.Script(f)).apply(ns)
}
```

At the end of `commandCallback`, you can return:

`JsCmds.Run("chainAction('" + valueOfResponse + "');")`